# What is "|safe" in odoo email template in field email_from

Tags: python, email, odoo

Odoo email template is using the email_from in the email template. in that i have seen some example like

`${(object.email or '')|safe}`

here is the screenshot

[image]

in that i am getting confused with the `|safe`, i wanted to know the use of '|safe'.

Comment: Odoo is using a templating language with *filters*, `| safe` applies some text filter (e.g. escaping HTML). See e.g. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters

Comment: not escaping html is what `|safe` does I would assume

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, It helped me a lot!!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

The framework will escape HTML automatically. But when you have to prevent the template from escaping the HTML you can use 'safe' filter. The use of safe filter on variables in which users are having control may leads to XSS (JS injection) vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Well Safe is basically a filters , Filters are separated from the variable by a pipe symbol (|).
So  the Output of `${(object.email or '')|safe}` will be produce as 
`${safe(object.email or '')}`.

> **Safe** is used to preventing the template from escaping the HTML content. Safe Filter explicitly marks a string as "safe", thus it
>   should not be automatically-escaped even  if auto-escaping is enabled 
>   by the ODOO framework.

For more details please visit:

> http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-manual-escaping
>   http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping